# What is the best practice to get objects keys from an array of object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have an array of products like this:

```
[
    {
        "productId":1001,
        "productCategory":"Category 3",
        "productName":"Product 1",
        "productImage":"https://picsum.photos/400?image=976",
        "productStock":false,
        "productPrice":"1318.287"
    },{
        "productId":1002,
        "productCategory":"Category 3",
        "productName":"Product 2",
        "productImage":"https://picsum.photos/400?image=765",
        "productStock":false,
        "productPrice":"4753.309"
    },{
        "productId":1003,
        "productCategory":"Category 3",
        "productName":"Product 3",
        "productImage":"https://picsum.photos/400?image=37",
        "productStock":false,
        "productPrice":"338.270"
    },
]
```

and I want to get the keys inside the object in an array `tabaleHeader` and the data in `tableData`

I've tried this and its working:

```
const [tableData, setTableData] = useState(data); // data is an array of products
const tableHeader = Object.keys(tableData[0]);
```

My Question is this a good practice or there is a better way to do this?

Comment: `const [products, setProducts] = useState(data);` -> `const [tableData, setProducts] = useState(data);` and `const [tableHeader, tableData] = [Object.keys(products[0]), products];` -> `const tableHeader = Object.keys(tableData[0]);`??? Why do you destructure `products` just to rename it?

Comment: thanks I will change that

Comment: Sure - as long as all the objects in the array have the same properties.  And not like the first one has a bunch of missing things.

Comment: `const tableHeader = Object.keys(products[0]);` this is OK, and there's no better way.

Answer (score 1):

No I wouldn't deconstruct the object because it is unnecessary. With the JSON below, I will show the way I would get the keys. I do this by using [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
let data = [
  {
    "productId": 1001,
    "productCategory": "Category 3",
    "productName": "Product 1",
    "productImage": "https://picsum.photos/400?image=976",
    "productStock": false,
    "productPrice": "1318.287"
  },
  {
    "productId": 1002,
    "productCategory": "Category 3",
    "productName": "Product 2",
    "productImage": "https://picsum.photos/400?image=765",
    "productStock": false,
    "productPrice": "4753.309"
  },
  {
    "productId": 1003,
    "productCategory": "Category 3",
    "productName": "Product 3",
    "productImage": "https://picsum.photos/400?image=37",
    "productStock": false,
    "productPrice": "338.270"
  }
];
let keys = data.map(i=>Object.keys(i));
console.log(keys);

//Or if you wanted the values
let vals = data.map(i=>Object.values(i));
console.log(vals);
```

Comment: And how is that better than using `Object.keys()`?

Comment: @KhalidAli, It is using `Object.keys()`. It is better than deconstructing the object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce to make sure that it grabs all keys even if few elements don't have all the keys:

```js
const data = [{
    productId: 1001,
    productCategory: 'Category 3',
    productName: 'Product 1',
    productImage: 'https://picsum.photos/400?image=976',
    productStock: false,
    productPrice: '1318.287',
  },
  {
    productId: 1002,
    productCategory: 'Category 3',
    productName: 'Product 2',
    productImage: 'https://picsum.photos/400?image=765',
    productStock: false,
    productPrice: '4753.309',
    bar: 'bar',
  },
  {
    productId: 1003,
    productCategory: 'Category 3',
    productName: 'Product 3',
    productImage: 'https://picsum.photos/400?image=37',
    productStock: false,
    productPrice: '338.270',
    foo: 'foo',
  },
]


const headers = Object.keys(
  data.reduce(
    (acc, curr) => ({
      ...acc,
      ...curr,
    }), {}
  )
)
console.log(headers)
```

Or, if the first element is supposed to have all the keys:

```js
Object.keys(data?.[0] ?? {})
```